# Installed security updates to lates kubuntu LTS now gets stuck during boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, kubuntu

I just installed the latest security updates on the latest kubuntu LTS. Then I rebooted. The boot process starts up normally until the Asus logo disappears (I have an Asus mobo that always shows during boot) and then I end up on this screen and it just hangs there. IDK what to do.

My computer:
Ryzen 3700x
Nvidia 2060 super
Asus x570 tuf gaming mobo with Bluetooth + WiFi

[Click to see the screen/errors my computer gives me when it hangs on boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKnc9.jpg)

Comment: "latest kubuntu lts" being 22.04 or 22.10?

Comment: Please be precise with details; *latest* may mean Kubuntu 20.04.5 as it was the *last* (or *latest* even if not newest*) released by Kubuntu; as it includes some of the software stack from the newer 22.04 release in the *respin* and thus always follows the newer release. Being specific allows us to avoid guessing what you mean.

Comment: Latest lts being 22.04

Comment: I can get to my lock screen only by going into grub and selecting the last driver I was using instead of the newest one. But I have to do it on every boot.

Comment: Please correct details in your question, comments are for us to ask for clarifications or get details from you, the comments will be deleted once issue is addressed. Your question still refers to an *unspecified latest* release (*[20.04.5 being released in Sept 2022](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/) thus is later than [22.04.1 which was the month before or Aug 2022](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/08/12/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-released/), or 22.04 which was April 2022*)

Comment: "*I just installed the latest security updates*" since Unattended Upgrades installs security updates for you automatically, it's unclear what commands you used, or what led you to believe that you must perform this minor task yourself.